# Convergence of the Cauchy product of two series of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

During these days, I reading a paper about analysis. I am confused about following question of a Cauchy-product of two convergent series.

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ be two series of real numbers and let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n$ be their Cauchy product. If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely to A and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$ converges conditionally to B, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n$ converges (not necessarily absolutely) to AB.

How to prove this proposition?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality